# Off work due to Dental work gone bad; employer being elusive about return to work, discrimination?

Tags: company-policy, termination, sickness, discrimination

New employer (2 weeks), temp job but hopeful for future regular employment. Had a dental procedure that injured the trigeminal nerve causing cluster headache for 6+ weeks.  Kept manager updated.  Ready to RTW - manager does not return my emails for 3 weeks, and now states I need to work with HR.

How do I handle this?  Can dentists/endodontist give off work slips? Is this discrimination? ie. not taking me back because I might get ill again?  I have an excellent 30 year work history. I do not want any negative impact to my work history now or in the future.   Help.

Comment: You may have to sue your dentist.

Comment: If you are simply looking to determine if your employer's actions constitute legal discrimination in your jurisdiction, I'd recommend talking to a lawyer.

Comment: What state/country are you in?

Comment: Unfortunately, `...now states I need to work with HR.` likely means you are no longer needed there, and the manager doesn't want to break the news to you. If there are contractual factors, then HR would be the only ones to address them.

Answer (score 2):

There is not discrimination here.  They needed someone to work, they brought you in as a temp worker and then after 2 weeks you were unable to continue working.  I understand that the circumstances were beyond your control.  It happens.  Had you been employed with the company for more than 12 months you could have been protected by the [Family and Medical Leave Act.](http://www.dol.gov/whd/fmla/)  However your short term employment means that you are not eligible for this protection.

Your best course of action is to find new employment.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are a temporary employee, there should be a contract stating your hours, pay, and other details. It may be that your 6 week absence has forced them to bring on another to replace you.

If you work in a jurisdiction that has at-will employment, they can let an employee go at any time a long as it wasn't for discriminatory reasons.  As a temp it is even easier to let you go, as long a they follow the contract terms.

It is possible that they will resign you when they have the next opening, but they may just toss your resume back in the pool of applicants. You have to talk to HR to see what they want you to do.